# all edits and additions must be approved by designated administrators/managers

Tags: php, mysql

ive a project in which a user can add record but that can published in the front end end only after it is verified and approved by admin. Please help me with the workflow and php code for this

Comment: i havent tried nything yet just got the project and im analysing whether it can be done or not.Can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

here is a thought , because this is what i have implemented in my system
we have bunch of data entry guys , they add data . Then asks administrator to review once it done administrator publishes. 
i have created one extra field `flag` and by default `flag` is `0` for newly entaied data.
once admin review the work he then updates the table setting `flag` to `1`

Comment: i was also thinking the same :-) and there is another functionality in this that All changes to content in the database should be traceable to the user who made the change. means whoever made any changes or gives approval name of that user should be shown

Comment: you are thinking in right way , my db stores created by, create date, updated by , update date

Comment: how can i show the name of the user whoever edit or delete record

Comment: in my system i am storing his/her `login name` in variable and when ever he updates or inserts data i add his name in query

Comment: im new to php can u help me with the query n database table plz.

Comment: I also dont know PHP :D

Comment: I can help you with queries can you let me know which action queries you need? like add, edit, delete, view etc Also provide me the conditions, db table structure. So that i can give the exact working queries..Thanks..

Comment: thanks ill let u know becoz ive just started my project

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem. What you need to do is very simple.

**First of all**

1. You need to create a table in database which store all the data you want.
2. You need to create 1 more `field` which store any variable. Example ('`0`' or '`pending`' as default ). Or you can store by using `INSERT` sql. What I mean is when you doing your form using php and then you insert the particular field as `0` or `pending`.

`INSERT INTO table ('name', 'contact', 'field')VALUES ('$name','$contact','0/pending')`

1. Create an admin site which use to verify and approve manually for the new user.
2. Do a transaction which can change the status of the `field`.
3. Update the `field` if admin approve to `1` or `approved`.

**PS*** if do not approve just let the field remain `0` or change the value to `rejected`.

1. Select the result by calling the specific value which according to the value you set in the `field`. For example you set the value is `approved`. Then what you should do is :

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = approve`

This should be what you want.

Comment: thanks sir. ill start working in this project. I might need ur help in future. Is there any way I can contact u in future.

Comment: you no need to worry about that. any question you can ask here when you face bottleneck on your code. stackoverflow have a lot of talents might help you out. but make sure when you ask something, you fulfill stackoverflow terms and conditions. good luck have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some raw steps.

- Create a flag (column) **is_published** in you users table.
- Set this flag default value as 0
- Provide an option in the admin panel with **approve** or **publish** button.
- On click of the above mentioned buttons run an ajax request update that particular column with value 1.
- In the front end part list only those records where is_published = 1 or is_published != 0

Hope this can solve your problem.